# What does rspec's eq method actually test for?

Tags: rspec

I'm a bit confused:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user = User.new
    end
end
```

I would have thought that all three of the following expectations would pass:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SessionsController do
    describe '#new' do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user, name: nil, email: nil, password: nil, password_confirmation: nil)}
        before { get :new }

        it { expect(assigns(:user)).to eq user }

        it { expect(assigns(:user)).to eq User.new }

        it "should assign stubbed user" do
            assigns(:user).should eq user
        end
    end
end
```

And yet I get this:
FFF

Failures:

```
  1) SessionsController#new should eq #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil>
     Failure/Error: it { expect(assigns(:user)).to eq user }

       expected: #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil>
            got: #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil>

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) SessionsController#new should eq #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil>
     Failure/Error: it { expect(assigns(:user)).to eq User.new }

       expected: #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil>
            got: #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil>

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) SessionsController#new should assign stubbed user
     Failure/Error: assigns(:user).should eq user

       expected: #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil>
            got: #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil>

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I mean what? The `Diff` section is even empty. If I was using the `be` matcher I'd understand, but I'm using `eq`, so what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

In ActiveRecord two model objects are considered equal if they have the same class and the same non-nil primary key values.

So if two identical objects have nil `id` values they are not equal.

See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L290

That may seem odd but it makes sense if you consider that those two objects if they were ever saved would be allocated two different `id` values by the database. So until their `id` of an ActiveRecord model object is allocated it cannot be compared meaningfully with another.

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing `user.attributes` using the eq method instead and it should pass.